# What does this mean: "error: invalid combination of multiple type-specifiers"

Tags: c++, gcc, compiler-errors, typedef

I'm getting a compiler error on FreeBSD:

```
error: invalid combination of multiple type-specifiers
```

From the C++ Code:

```
typedef unsigned off_t uoff_t;
```

Not sure what the gcc compiler is trying to tell me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `typedef std::make_unsigned_t< off_t > uoff_t;` [since C++14](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned#Helper_types) instead to achieve the desired effect.

Use `typedef std::make_unsigned< off_t >::type uoff_t;` [since C++11](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/make_unsigned).

Use `typedef boost::make_unsigned< off_t >::type uoff_t;` before C++11.

Answer (score 5):

Unless `off_t` is a macro, it's simply a syntax error.

`unsigned` is not something you can add to a typedef'ed type or use to modify such a type.

Cheers & hth.,